How to Merge Two Excel Sheets Based on Composite Key and Handle Missing Keys?
I have two Excel sheets with the following data:
Sheet1:



LOC_NBR
CATEG_CODE
KEY_CODE
DATA_TXT
LOOK_UP_KEY_1




666
FUNC
CHLLD
0
666FUNCCHLLD


1107
FUNC
CHLLD
1
1107FUNCCHLLD


1111
FUNC
CHLLD
0
1111FUNCCHLLD


1141
FUNC
CHLLD
0
1141FUNCCHLLD


1151
FUNC
CHLLD
1
1151FUNCCHLLD


1198
FUNC
CHLLD
1
1198FUNCCHLLD



Note: LOOK_UP_KEY_1 is the combination of LOC_NBR, CATEG_CODE, KEY_CODE.
Sheet2:



LOC_NBR
CATEG_CODE
KEY_CODE
DATA_TXT
LOOK_UP_KEY_2




666
FUNC
CHLLD
1
666FUNCCHLLD


1107
FUNC
CHLLD
0
1107FUNCCHLLD


1111
FUNC
CHLLD
0
1111FUNCCHLLD


1141
FUNC
CHLLD
1
1141FUNCCHLLD


1151
FUNC
CHLLD
1
1151FUNCCHLLD


2007
FUNC
CHLLD
0
2007FUNCCHLLD



Note: LOOK_UP_KEY_2 is the combination of LOC_NBR, CATEG_CODE, KEY_CODE.
Expected Result in Sheet3:



LOOK_UP_KEY_1
LOOK_UP_KEY_2
DATA_TXT_1
DATA_TXT_2




666FUNCCHLLD
666FUNCCHLLD
0
1


1107FUNCCHLLD
1107FUNCCHLLD
1
0


1111FUNCCHLLD
1111FUNCCHLLD
0
0


1141FUNCCHLLD
1141FUNCCHLLD
0
1


1151FUNCCHLLD
1151FUNCCHLLD
1
1


1198FUNCCHLLD
Not Present
1
NA


Not Present
2007FUNCCHLLD
NA
0



Requirements:

Merge Sheet1 and Sheet2 based on LOOK_UP_KEY_1 and LOOK_UP_KEY_2.
When keys match, include the DATA_TXT values from both sheets.
If a key from Sheet1 is not present in Sheet2, show "Not Present" for LOOK_UP_KEY_2 and NA for DATA_TXT_2.
If a key from Sheet2 is not present in Sheet1, show "Not Present" for LOOK_UP_KEY_1 and NA for DATA_TXT_1.

I would appreciate guidance on how to achieve this in Excel.

I would consider the use of index() with match(). Many examples on here.

You could also use Power Query included in Excel since 2010.

Since there's no version restrictions, =XLOOKUP() could work as well.

As Ron mentioned you can use Power Query.

If your data is in Excel tables (Ctrl+T to turn a range of data into a table).
Note - These are named Table1 and Table2 in the example code below.
From the toolbar select Data > Get Data > From Other Sources > Blank Query.
In the Window that opens select Advanced Editor.
Copy and paste this code into the Advanced Editor and press Done:


let 
    Table1_Src = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Table1_DataType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table1_Src,{{"LOC_NBR", Int64.Type}, {"CATEG_CODE", type text}, {"KEY_CODE", type text}, {"DATA_TXT", type text}, {"LOOK_UP_KEY_1", type text}}),

    Table2_Src = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    Table2_DataType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table2_Src,{{"LOC_NBR", Int64.Type}, {"CATEG_CODE", type text}, {"KEY_CODE", type text}, {"DATA_TXT", type text}, {"LOOK_UP_KEY_2", type text}}),

    MergeTables = Table.NestedJoin(Table1_DataType, {"LOOK_UP_KEY_1"}, Table2_DataType, {"LOOK_UP_KEY_2"}, "Table2", JoinKind.FullOuter),
    ExpandTable2 = Table.ExpandTableColumn(MergeTables, "Table2", {"LOC_NBR", "CATEG_CODE", "KEY_CODE", "DATA_TXT", "LOOK_UP_KEY_2"}, {"LOC_NBR.1", "CATEG_CODE.1", "KEY_CODE_2", "DATA_TXT_2", "LOOK_UP_KEY_2"}),
    RemoveOtherColumns = Table.SelectColumns(ExpandTable2,{"LOOK_UP_KEY_1", "LOOK_UP_KEY_2", "DATA_TXT", "DATA_TXT_2"}),
    RenameColumns = Table.RenameColumns(RemoveOtherColumns,{{"DATA_TXT", "DATA_TXT_1"}}),
    ReplacedValue1 = Table.ReplaceValue(RenameColumns,null,"Not Present",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"LOOK_UP_KEY_1", "LOOK_UP_KEY_2"}),
    ReplacedValue2 = Table.ReplaceValue(ReplacedValue1,null,"NA",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"DATA_TXT_1", "DATA_TXT_2"})
in
    ReplacedValue2

Press Close & Load to load the table to a new sheet.


Power Query option
let
  tb1 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name = "Table1"]}[Content],
  tb2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name = "Table2"]}[Content],
  tb1Columns = Table.RenameColumns(
    Table.SelectColumns(tb1, {"DATA_TXT", "LOOK_UP_KEY_1"}),
    {{"DATA_TXT", "DATA_TXT_1"}}
  ),
  tb1tb2fullOuterJoin = Table.NestedJoin(
    tb1Columns,
    {"LOOK_UP_KEY_1"},
    tb2,
    {"LOOK_UP_KEY_2"},
    "Table2",
    JoinKind.FullOuter
  ),
  expanded = Table.ExpandTableColumn(
    tb1tb2fullOuterJoin,
    "Table2",
    {"DATA_TXT", "LOOK_UP_KEY_2"},
    {"DATA_TXT_2", "LOOK_UP_KEY_2"}
  ),
  null2NotPresent = Table.ReplaceValue(
    expanded,
    null,
    "Not Present",
    Replacer.ReplaceValue,
    {"LOOK_UP_KEY_1", "LOOK_UP_KEY_2"}
  ),
  null2NA = Table.ReplaceValue(
    null2NotPresent,
    null,
    "NA",
    Replacer.ReplaceValue,
    {"DATA_TXT_1", "DATA_TXT_2"}
  ),
  reorderedCols = Table.ReorderColumns(
    null2NA,
    {"LOOK_UP_KEY_1", "LOOK_UP_KEY_2", "DATA_TXT_1", "DATA_TXT_2"}
  )
in
  reorderedCols



Without PQ for 'join'ing fun:
You will need Microsoft 365.
Create these functions in Name Manager (these will be available in all the sheets):
_full_outer 
= LAMBDA(
    A, B, dataA, dataB,
    keyNotPresent, dataNotPresent,
    LET(
      rowIndex,
      LAMBDA(arr, start, HSTACK(SEQUENCE(ROWS(arr), , start, 2), arr)),
      items,
      TAKE(SORT(VSTACK(rowIndex(A, 1), rowIndex(B, 2))), , -1),
      distinct,
      UNIQUE(items),
      isA,
      COUNTIFS(A, distinct),
      isB,
      COUNTIFS(B, distinct),
      outputRow,
      HSTACK(
        _include(isA, A, keyNotPresent),
        _include(isB, B, keyNotPresent),
        _include(isA, dataA, dataNotPresent),
        _include(isB, dataB, dataNotPresent)),
      outputRow))

_include    
=LAMBDA(_is_present,_rows,_not_present_row, IF(_is_present,CHOOSEROWS(_rows,_offset_indices(_is_present)), _not_present_row)  )

_offset_indices 
=LAMBDA(offsets, SCAN(0,offsets,LAMBDA(a,c, a+c)))

Create two tables for Sheet 1 & Sheet 2 and enter the following in the first cell in Sheet 3:
=_full_outer(Sheet1[LOOK_UP_KEY_1], Sheet2[LOOK_UP_KEY_2], Sheet1[DATA_TXT], Sheet2[DATA_TXT], "Not Present", "NA")


